# How to migrate custom list forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0, migration, custom-form

We have several lists in our WSS 3.0 environment where NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx and DisplayForm.aspx are customized via SharePoint Designer 2007. Now we plan to upgrade to SharePoint Foundation 2010 and are unsure how that customization will behave during migration?
We did not create a new form (like NewForm_custom.aspx) but modified the existing one.

From my understanding the customized forms is stored in the content DB which will be upgraded -so everything will work and look the same after migration?!

(Yeah, I know, pretty unrealistic. So who what's to tell me what we are going to face and what the best pratices here are?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should be ok. The biggest thing is you may find that the UI is going to end up inconsistent between the list views and the list forms. For example I had a dataview that we used and it still ended up showing the old 2007 tool bar and the ribbon didn't display as such we had to do some manual fixes on the views / forms that misbehaved but it really wasn't that big of a deal.

However, you may or may not run into these sort of issues.

That being said I highly recommend you get a test server up and practice the upgrade and test everything before upgrading your production environment. This is really the only guaranteed way to make sure everything behaves as you expect.

---

**Update: Links**

[Test-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#VerifyCustom)

[STSADM Pre Upgrade Check](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262231.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Testing goes without saying, but we are still in planning phase. When it gets serious a test farm will be used. 
Does anyone else got trouble with migrating custom forms?

Comment: If you run through the 2007 SP2 Pre Upgrade Check STSADM command and the 2010 Test-SPContentDatabase Powershell command (when you get to testing) and everything checks out you are most likely ok (Links added to original answer). Most important thing you can do is make sure these things are all explicitly called out in your plan.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with the upgrade, but regardless you should get a test server up and do some testing. Import a couple of the larger lists into the test server and run through the upgrade process. As I said, it should convert everything fine, however you will know sure that way.